# Can simple calculations on variable length iterables be made faster in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm calculating the euclidean distance between two vectors represented by tuples.

```
(u[0]-v[0])**2 + (u[1]-v[1])**2 + (u[3]-v[3])**2 ...
```

The hard-coded way of doing this is pretty fast. However, I would like to make no assumptions about the length of these vectors. That results in solutions like:

```
sum([(a-b)**2 for a, b in izip(u, v)]) # Faster without generator
```

or

```
sum = 0
for i in xrange(len(u)):
    sum += (u[i]-v[i])**2
```

which turn out to be much (at least twice) slower than the first version. Is there some smart way of optimizing this, **without resorting to NumPy/SciPy?** I'm aware that those packages offer the fastest way of doing such things, but at the moment, I'm more trying to get experience with optimizing "bare Python". What I found works fast is to dynamically build a string that defines the function and `exec()` it, but that's really a last resort, I would say...

The requirements:

- CPython 2.7
- Standard library only
- "Real" (e.g. no `exec()`), pure Python

Even though my question is about the matter of small operations in general, you may assume in your solution that one of the vectors remains the same over several function calls.

Comment: You've just got to [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html). In solution #2 you are creating a list that you don't need. Try `sum((a-b)**2 for a,b in izip(u,v))`. In solution #3 you are indexing too often. Try `for a,b in izip(u,v): sum += (a-b)**2`

Comment: He commented that it's faster as a list than a generator. Sounds like he knows what he's doing.

Comment: @Rob I actually did a lot of timing and could not come up with a solution that comes close to the hard-coded variant. That's why I posted my question here. As I already noted, #2 is faster with the list than without (since generators give some overhead, and the vectors themselves are not huge).

Comment: I think the point of #3 is to avoid using izip.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with building the function as a string and using exec to define it. That as how [collections.namedtuple](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0f5e1e642dc3/Lib/collections.py#l361) works.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien - Okay. I suppose I didn't completely understand your question. Perhaps you could edit the question and list the things that you've already tried.

Comment: @unutbu At least it gives problems with code inspection, and cProfiler isn't happy with the sudden appearance of a new function either. Perhaps there's some pattern for that which I'm not aware of?

Comment: Coding is often a balance between competing interests. Defining the function with `exec` may be the fastest way using pure Python, but you may have to give something else up. C'est la vie.

Comment: @unutbu Well, I was hoping for something that circumvents whatever makes the solutions above slow, not using `exec` magic.

Comment: "optimizing bare python" is not always a useful skill. CPython has never pretended to be the best performing solution for a given programming problem, but it does provide extreme efficiency for the programmer and the reader's time. Once so much machine time is being burned up by your solution that it would be advisable to optimize, it is time to look at numpy/scipy, pypy, or exec/byte-code tricks. That you understand your iterator solution is slower due to the overhead of the iterator compared to the small length of iteration is probably an indicator that you've grasped the issue here.

Comment: @marr75 The point is rather that the first solutions shows that CPython can be quite fast and I find it hard to accept that it being slightly more dynamic makes it that much slower. Of course, none of this is production code.

Comment: Note also that there are some situations that the accumulator style for-loop in your third example will yield terrible performance. Many list implementations will pre-allocate memory (which is almost certainly wasteful because you know the EXACT size of sequence you need) in batches as you overflow the old allocation of the list. Further, these allocations can lead to a fragmented heap, which in many applications starts to resemble a memory leak.

Comment: One of the main reasons the first implementation is so fast is that there is no function call overhead. Someone might correct me, but I am fairly sure python is able to effectively "inline" (the calls amount to a single operation so a function call would be pointless) those basic operators (+, **, []) require. In the other implementations, much more expensive function call overhead is added.

Comment: @marr75 Plausible. So then, is there a way to minimize those without `exec`?

Comment: PyPy, c extensions, bytecode magic. I would promote all of those solutions as superior to exec in most cases. The use case in your post is nicely constrained, but I have no doubt that it is demonstrative of a more complex problem (or similar to a more complex problem you'll face some day).

Comment: In #3, I would avoid calling the accumulation variable `sum` ;)

Comment: To add to @marr75's point: For every data size I throw at things (except _huge_ lists, where the allocation cost matters), the best solution is at least 73% as slow as the worst. Just running any of them, unchanged, they all improve by a factor of at least 10x.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in #2, using a genexp instead of a list comprehension goes from slightly slower in CPython 2.7 to slightly faster in CPython 3.3 to blazingly faster in PyPy 1.9. As in: 24.28 vs. 25.09, 20.20 vs. 19.78, and 2.31 vs. 1.35.

Comment: @abarnert PyPy ftw! Inlining calls to the `__next__` method and not having to allocate any space make all the difference.

Comment: At some point, the question becomes, "Can I make CPython 2.7's function call and iteration overheads less expensive by wishing?" The answer is, unfortunately, no.

Comment: @marr75 It is not that simple. Calling `sum()` seems to be very expensive for some reason, whereas calling `izip()` is not. The question still is how to do best with the given constraints (mine and those of CPython itself, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm understanding is that you don't really need to make the code faster, you just want to know why it's slower. To answer that, let's look at the disassembly. For the purposes of this discussion, I'm going to wrap each method in a function call, the loading of `u` and `v` and the return command can be ignored in each disassembly.

```
def test1(u, v):
    return (u[0]-v[0])**2 + (u[1]-v[1])**2 + (u[3]-v[3])**2

dis.dis(test1)
 0 LOAD_FAST                0 (u)
 3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
 6 BINARY_SUBSCR       
 7 LOAD_FAST                1 (v)
10 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
13 BINARY_SUBSCR       
14 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
15 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
18 BINARY_POWER        
19 LOAD_FAST                0 (u)
22 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
25 BINARY_SUBSCR       
26 LOAD_FAST                1 (v)
29 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
32 BINARY_SUBSCR       
33 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
34 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
37 BINARY_POWER        
38 BINARY_ADD          
39 LOAD_FAST                0 (u)
42 LOAD_CONST               4 (3)
45 BINARY_SUBSCR       
46 LOAD_FAST                1 (v)
49 LOAD_CONST               4 (3)
52 BINARY_SUBSCR       
53 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
54 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
57 BINARY_POWER        
58 BINARY_ADD          
59 RETURN_VALUE
```

I cut the first example off at a length of 3 because it would just repeat the same pattern over and over. You can quickly see that there is no function call overhead and pretty much the interpreter is doing the minimum possible work on these operands to achieve your result.

```
def test2(u, v):
    sum((a-b)**2 for a, b in izip(u, v))

dis.dis(test2)
 0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sum)
 3 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 02C6F458, file "<pyshell#10>", line 2>)
 6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
 9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (izip)
12 LOAD_FAST                0 (u)
15 LOAD_FAST                1 (v)
18 CALL_FUNCTION            2
21 GET_ITER            
22 CALL_FUNCTION            1
25 CALL_FUNCTION            1
28 RETURN_VALUE
```

What we see here is that we create a function out of the generator expression, load 2 globals (sum and izip, global lookups are slower than local lookups, we can't avoid making them once but if they're going to be called in a tight loop, many people assign them to a local, such as `_izip` or `_sum`), and then suffer 4 expensive bytecode operations in a row, calling izip, getting the iterator from the generator, calling the function created by the generator, and then calling the sum function (which will consume the iterator and add each item before returning).

```
def test3(u, v):
    sum = 0
    for i in xrange(len(u)):
        sum += (u[i]-v[i])**2

dis.dis(test3)
 0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
 3 STORE_FAST               2 (sum)

 6 SETUP_LOOP              52 (to 61)
 9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (xrange)
12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
15 LOAD_FAST                0 (u)
18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
21 CALL_FUNCTION            1
24 GET_ITER            
25 FOR_ITER                32 (to 60)
28 STORE_FAST               3 (i)

31 LOAD_FAST                2 (sum)
34 LOAD_FAST                0 (u)
37 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
40 BINARY_SUBSCR       
41 LOAD_FAST                1 (v)
44 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
47 BINARY_SUBSCR       
48 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
49 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
52 BINARY_POWER        
53 INPLACE_ADD         
54 STORE_FAST               2 (sum)
57 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           25
60 POP_BLOCK           
61 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
64 RETURN_VALUE
```

What we see here is a more straightforward version of what is happening in `test2`. No generator expression or call to sum, but we've replaced that function call overhead with an unnecessary function call by doing `xrange(len(u))` instead of the faster solution suggested by @Lucas Malor.

```
def test4(u, v):
    mysum = 0
    for a, b in izip(u, v) :
        mysum += (a-b)**2
    return mysum

dis.dis(test4)
 0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
 3 STORE_FAST               2 (mysum)

 6 SETUP_LOOP              47 (to 56)
 9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (izip)
12 LOAD_FAST                0 (u)
15 LOAD_FAST                1 (v)
18 CALL_FUNCTION            2
21 GET_ITER            
22 FOR_ITER                30 (to 55)
25 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
28 STORE_FAST               3 (a)
31 STORE_FAST               4 (b)

34 LOAD_FAST                2 (mysum)
37 LOAD_FAST                3 (a)
40 LOAD_FAST                4 (b)
43 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
44 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
47 BINARY_POWER        
48 INPLACE_ADD         
49 STORE_FAST               2 (mysum)
52 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           22
55 POP_BLOCK           

56 LOAD_FAST                2 (mysum)
59 RETURN_VALUE
```

The above represents @Lucas Malor's contribution and it's faster in a few ways. It replaces subscript operations with unpacking while reducing the number of calls to 1. This is, in many cases, as fast you're going to achieve with the constraints you've given us.

Note that it would only be worth `eval`uating a run-time generated string similar to the function in test1 if you were going to call the function enough times to merit the overhead. Note also that as the length of u and v becomes increasingly large (which is typically how algorithms of this type are evaluated) the function call overhead of the other solutions becomes increasingly small and therefore, in most cases, the most readable solution is vastly superior. At the same time, even though it's slower in small cases, if the length of your sequences, u and v, may be very long, I recommend a generator expression as opposed to a list comprehension. The memory savings will cause much faster execution in most cases (and faster gc).

Overall, my recommendation is that the tiny speedup in cases of short sequences is just not worth the increase in code size and inconsistent behavior with other implementations of python you're looking at by performing micro-optimizations. The "best" solution is almost certainly `test2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive contributions to the discussion and let's close with this. It was challenging to shave some seconds off my code without using special libraries and it's great to have some more insight in the underlying mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks, @ThijsvanDien! It was an interesting discussion!

Answer (score 2):

```
mysum = 0
for a, b in izip(u, v) :
    mysum += (a-b)**2
```

About 35% faster than #3

PS: have you tried [Cython](http://www.cython.org/) (not CPython) or [Shedskin](https://code.google.com/p/shedskin/)?

Comment: For what input data? When I test with CPython 2.7.2 with `u=[random.random() for _ in range(10000)]` and the same for `v`, `timeit(f, number=10000)` for your version is 29.80 vs. 29.84, barely a difference at all. (And #2 is 24.28.)

Comment: I used a tuple of 5 elements. They are vectors after all. You can't find 10000 dimensions even in string theory :-P

Comment: @Thijs van Dien: I tested it in Python 2.7.3 using cProfile.run() instead of timeit.timeit().

Comment: It is noticeably faster, indeed. Even more so if doing `(a-b) * (a-b)`. Interesting that `itertools` seem to have less overhead than a built-in function like `sum()`.

Comment: @LucasMalor: I used to routinely work with 10000-element vectors representing that many dimensions when analyzing medical data ;-)

Comment: @Thijs van Dien: take a look to [array](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) module too... or ctypes, if you want to go mad.

Comment: @liori: I don't think they are _space_ vectors ;-)

Comment: @LucasMalor: Some data mining methods treat such data exactly as vectors in a multidimensional space. I did calculate Euclidean distances on them…

Comment: In this exercise, sequences of 5 elements are trivial. If he was trying to optimize for sequences of anything less than say, 10 items, he could just write out each and every case and not have to use any kind of iteration. When you're optimizing a sequence based algorithm for unknown cases, you optimize for the large, the run time in small cases will be predictable and short.